# splitting list with equal contents

Tags: python

for example I have the following list:

```
contents= ["i have two pens","prices = 5$","made in ____ and ____"]
```

I want to split them such a way that it has the same content as following:

```
array[0]= ["i", "have", "two", "pens", ""]
array[1]= ["prices", "=", "5$", " ", " "]
array[2]= ["made", "in", "____", "and" ,"____"]
```

that means, each array has equal number of contents (5 here). The code I am using is:

```
array = [phrase.split() for phrase in contents]
```

but surely, it doesn't split them with equal contents. Can anyone suggest me how can I solve this using python?

Comment: Could you explain why you want this; it may be an XY problem. For example, `itertools.izip_longest` may solve it without interfering with the splitting.

Comment: Because I want to use a loop. I have only one content in an array (e.g. array[5]). so when it iterates array[i][1], it gets the error "IndexError: list index out of range", as there is no array[5][1].

Comment: Not really the broader view I was hoping for, but it looks like: you want to iterate over all the lists simultaneously, looking at the `i`th element in each one, but need to pad the shorter lists. [Step this way](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest).

Comment: Why is the first list padded with empty strings, and the second with one-space strings?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to check which is the longest array and then pad the other ones, like this:

```
array = [phrase.split() for phrase in contents]
x = max(len(i) for i in array)
result = [i + [''] * (x - len(i)) for i in array]
```

Complicated but gives you the result you're looking for.

Comment: I suspect `itertools.izip_longest` is really what the OP is looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

This is another choice, May be also complicated.

```
from itertools import izip_longest

array = [phrase.split() for phrase in contents]
l = izip_longest(*array, fillvalue=u'')
result = [list(t) for t in zip(*l)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick demo to expand on my comment, using [`izip_longest` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> contents = ["i have two pens",
                "prices = 5$",
                "made in ____ and ____"]
>>> array = [phrase.split() for phrase in contents]
>>> for t in izip_longest(*array, fillvalue=" "):
        print t


('i', 'prices', 'made')
('have', '=', 'in')
('two', '5$', '____')
('pens', ' ', 'and')
(' ', ' ', '____')
```

You don't need to modify `array`, this pads for you as you iterate over the sublists.