# Python: Complete list with items

Tags: python, list, syntax

Let's say I have many lists. Each of these lists may have different length. The thing I want to do is to complete each of this lists with (for example) string "EMPTY". Is there a build-in function or very simple set of commands which can provide that?

I think that it is possible in the 2 for loops.

```
for list in lists:
    for i in range(0,10):
        try:
            val = list[i]
        except IndexError:
            // list[i] = "EMPTY" 
            list.append("EMPTY")
```

As everybody who works with Python knows, Python has a huge amount of little features to work with strings, lists, etc... so my question is whether is there a simpler way.

For example:

```
for list in lists:
    list.complete("EMPTY",10)
```

Comment: If you're doing this because you want to iterate simultaneously over multiple lists, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24946445/3001761).

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways. Here's one, but I don't pretend that this is the only way:

```
def complete(lst, fill_value, desired_length):
    return lst + [fill_value] * (desired_length - len(lst))
```

That is not safe if your `fill_value` is mutable, such as a list or dict, but strings are fine.

Also, it returns a new list rather than editing the provided list. If you want to edit it:

```
def complete(lst, fill_value, desired_length):
    return lst.extend([fill_value] * (desired_length - len(lst)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for alist in lists:
    alist.extend(["EMPTY"]*(10-len(alist))
```

maybe ? as one of many ways to complete this ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many ways to do this, but this is what came to my mind first:

```
def complete_lists(lists, length, filler):
    for lst in lists: #btw, don't use list as a variable name
        lst.extend([filler for i in range(len(lst), length)])
```

You can also do it in a scary oneliner for fun:

```
def complete_lists(lists, length, filler):
    __ = [lst.extend([filler for i in range(len(l), length)]) for lst in lists]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe a little bit shorter

```
n = 10 
for l in lists:
    l.extend((("EMPTY "*(n-len(l))).split())
```

Comment: Please, don't encourage people to use `list` as a variable name

Answer (score 0):

This is easily doable with the `fillvalue` argument to `itertools.iziplongest`

First import the necessary modules and create your data:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> import itertools
>>> lists = (list('abc'), list('defg'), list('hijkl'))
>>> lists
(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'])
```

Now, we can zip them according to the longest list, with the desired fill value:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(list(itertools.izip_longest(*lists, fillvalue='EMPTY')))
[('a', 'd', 'h'),
 ('b', 'e', 'i'),
 ('c', 'f', 'j'),
 ('EMPTY', 'g', 'k'),
 ('EMPTY', 'EMPTY', 'l')]
```

Finally, demonstrate transposing the lists so that the desired end result is obtained:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(list(zip(*itertools.izip_longest(*lists, fillvalue='EMPTY'))))
[('a', 'b', 'c', 'EMPTY', 'EMPTY'),
 ('d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'EMPTY'),
 ('h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer to append **None**, instead of a string, to your lists.

For example, with:

```
def completeList(lst):
    while len(lst) < 10:
        lst.append(None)
    return lst
```

You could do the following:

```
for lst in lists:
    lst = completeList(lst)
```

Which will turn something like:

```
lists = [[1, 2, 4], 
         ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'], 
         ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']]
```

Into:

```
Out: [[1, 2, 4, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
      ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', None, None, None, None, None],
      ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']]
```

Using **None** is only marginally more efficient, but will potentially allow you to perform more straightforward operations on your lists later in the code.  For example, None will evaluate as false in circumstances where the string 'EMPTY' will not.